# Is there a ghci colon-command to hide a package?

Tags: haskell, ihaskell

At present I'm using ihaskell to learn about some libraries. IHaskell is still hazardous, and I can not do:

```
-- This doesn't work:   ":ext PackageImports", the kernel hangs
-- This doesn't work:   "{-# LANGUAGE PackageImports #-}", the kernel hangs
import Codec.Crypto.RSA.Pure
import qualified "crypto-api" Crypto.Random                                         as CR
import           Control.Monad.CryptoRandom
```

Without "PackageImports", I get an error message:

```
Ambiguous interface for ‘Crypto.Random’: it was found in multiple packages: crypto-api-0.13.2 cryptonite-0.7
```

My question is, is there a colon command inside ghci that would allow me to hide the cryptonite package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```
:set -hide-package cryptonite
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately is not implemented yet by iHaskell